# Allowing configure in send_command in netmiko

Tags: python, netmiko

I'm trying to use netmiko to work as well as `cli_command` module for Ansible. `cli_command` allows to send arbitrary list of strings into device (f.e. `configure`, `sh te 1/0/1`, `exit` in a single multi-line string) and it works without issues.

Netmiko requires a separate `send_config` and `send_command` and causes hangs for connection if 'configure' is send as a command.

Is there any way to force netmiko to accept modified prompt in configure mode like it's a normal command?

Basically, I want this to work:

```
connection.send_command('''
  configure
  shutdown te 1/0/1
  end
  show interface te 1/0/1
''')
```

Answer (score 1):

`send_command` works by detecting the device prompt (pattern-based), then it knows the command is done when the prompt is detected. This happens every command when you send them using `send_command`.

Instead, use `send_command_timing` it's another version of `send_command` but delay-based and doesn't look for the device prompt.

```py
from netmiko.ssh_dispatcher import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "session_log": "log.log",
}

with ConnectHandler(**device) as ssh_conn:
    output = ssh_conn.send_command_timing(  # Notice the send_command_timing()
        command_string="""
    configure terminal
    interface loopback 925
    shutdown
    end
    show interface loopback 925
    """
    )
print(output)
```

Also check this [blog post](https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko.html#signature) on Python for Network Engineers, I think you will find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error in send command:

"netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
Pattern not detected: '{device hostname}\#' in output."

And I can confirm tat the solution proposed by @Tes3away fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30473455)

Answer (score 0):

As in this example, you can take advantage of both the timing and prompt properties.

```
prompt_gpon_fnk = net_connect.find_prompt()
hostname_fnk = prompt_gpon_fnk.strip("<" + ">")
print(hostname_fnk)
net_connect.send_command_timing("enable")
net_connect.send_command_timing("undo smart")
output = net_connect.send_command_timing("config")
print("config moda girildi")
net_connect.send_command_timing("acl 2010 ")
net_connect.send_command_timing("quit")
net_connect.send_command_timing("save")
```